# Nice way to return from a function within mutex locked code in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, mutex

I'm using a `std::mutex` called `DXGI_LOCK` and I have written the following code simply to get the value of a pointer:

```
const IDXGIFactory& GetDXGIFactory() {
    DXGI_LOCK.lock();
    IDXGIFactory* localCopy = nullptr;
    try {
        localCopy = pDxgiFactory;
    }
    catch (...) {
        DXGI_LOCK.unlock();
        throw;
    }
    DXGI_LOCK.unlock();
    return *localCopy;
}
```

I'm just a hobby C++ programmer, and this seems a bit over-the-top. So, before I go using this pattern everywhere: Is there a better way to use mutex locks in a safe way in C++ code?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`std::lock_guard<std::mutex>` is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm using a std::mutex called DXGI_LOCK

Try this:

```
const IDXGIFactory& GetDXGIFactory() {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(DXGI_LOCK); // performs RAII unlock
                                                 // on scope exit
    return *pDxgiFactory;
}
```